# LiveData onChanged called multiple times with the same data when using FirebaseAuth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, android-livedata

I have a login activity which implement Firebase Authentication using email and password. What it does is send the user inputted email and password to FirebaseAuth function and retrieve the response via LiveData, then observe it.

The problem is, when the login failed or credentials is invalid, it should toast a message once, but what really happened is it toast multiple times, maybe more than 4 times (it made the toast showed for very long time).

**LoginActivity**

```
    private fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String){
        val authResult = viewModel.authWithEmailPassword(email, password)
        handleAuthenticationResult(authResult)
    }

    private fun handleAuthenticationResult(authResult: LiveData<Resource<AuthResult>>){
        authResult.observe(this, object : Observer<Resource<AuthResult>>{
            override fun onChanged(it: Resource<AuthResult>?) {
                when(it){
                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        toggleLoadingIndicator(true)
                    }
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        toggleLoadingIndicator(false)

                        val isNewUser = it.data.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser ?: true

                        if(isNewUser) gotoIntroActivity()
                        else gotoMainActivity()
                    }
                    is Resource.Failure -> {
                        toggleLoadingIndicator(false)

                        when(it.throwable){
                            is FirebaseAuthException -> Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, getString(R.string.error_credentials_invalid), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            else -> Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, getString(R.string.error_login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

**ViewModel**

```
    fun authWithEmailPassword(email: String, password: String): LiveData<Resource<AuthResult>>{
        return AuthRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    }
```

**FirebaseAuth**

```
    private var authResult: MutableLiveData<Resource<AuthResult>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: String, password: String): LiveData<Resource<AuthResult>>{
        authResult.value = Resource.Loading()

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener{
                    if(it.isSuccessful) authResult.value = Resource.Success(it.result!!)
                    else authResult.value = Resource.Failure(it.exception!!)
                }

        return authResult
    }
```

**Resource**

```
sealed class Resource<out T> {
    class Loading<out T> : Resource<T>()
    data class Success<out T>(val data: T) : Resource<T>()
    data class Failure<out T>(val throwable: Throwable) : Resource<T>()
}
```

Why this happened and how to fix this? Should I remove the observer everytime the `Resource.Failure` triggered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LiveData is a thing you create and subscribe to only once. In your case, you subscribe to it every time you get an auth result, hence multiple duplicate events.

In order to fix this, do the following:

1. In your viewmodel, declare the livedata:

`val authResult: MutableLiveData<Resource<AuthResult>> = MutableLiveData()`

2. In your Activity's onCreate(), subscribe to this liveData:

`viewModel.authResult.observe(this, ... [the rest of your code]`

3. when you get the auth result, just post it to the liveData. Do not re-subscribe to the live data, do not create a new live data.

`authResult.postValue(resource)`

Comment: If I declare authresult livedata in viewmodel, how do I post value into it?
Should I observe the livedata that comes from FirebaseAuth class in my viewmodel?

Or should I declare the livedata in FirebaseAuth class instead?

Comment: You can pass the livedata to AuthRepository.signInWithEmailAndPassword as a parameter

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm just thinking of something, would not passing the livedata as parameter to repository could leak the viewmodel? What will happen if repository is still fetching data and the user close the activity?

Comment: Technically, yes, you are leaking the viewmodel. But when activity is subscribing to a livedata, the first parameter it is passing is its lifecycle. So when you close the activity, it automatically unsubscribes from the livedata.

Comment: your answer also help me to solve my problem with executed multiple times in livedata  . thank's body